# WebView automatic reload Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, webview, reload

Basically I need to refresh or reload a web view every 5 or so seconds once a button is pressed.

I have got it to load a webpage when the button is pressed. But the timer I originally wrote just crashes after the specified time. This is what I have done with the button and web view.

```
- (IBAction)SendGPSData:(id)sender {
    NSURL *myURL =[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.co.uk"];
    NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
    [myWebView2 loadRequest:myRequest];

}
```

Comment: Can you post your timer code?

Answer (score 3):

For `UIButton`

```
- (IBAction)SendGPSData:(id)sender 
  {
   [webView reload];

  }
```

and for `NSTimer`

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(WebViewLoad:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

-(void)WebViewLoad:(NSTimer *)theTimer
{
[webView reload];
}
```